# Google Groups Invitation Error

Tags: google-groups

I have received an invitation to a Google Group by my boss (who is a manager of the Google Group) to my work email.

I have created a Google account using the work email address and am receiving the error

> You must be a member of this group to view and participate in it.  Membership is by invitation only.  This group is invite only, so you may not apply for membership. However, you may contact the owner.

However, my boss confirmed I am a member in the Google Group. This has only started happening recently. My other co-workers were able to successfully login using the same work email address by creating a Google account from it. Some  other co-workers are having the same issue.

Is there a member limit for the free version of Google Groups? Does the owner of the Google Group (my boss's boss) have to change any permission settings?

Comment: Your boss isn't "forwarding" or copy pasting the invite, right?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a member limit for the free version of google groups?

No, there isn't.

> Does the owner of the google groups (my bosses boss) have to change any permission settings?

No.

---

Double check that you are using exactly the same email address that was used to send the invitation and not an alias as the primary or an alternative email address for you Google account.

References

- [Find and join a group](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1067205?hl=en)
- [Create a Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441?hl=en)
- [Sign in to your Google Account with another email address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347?hl=en)